# Find all $x \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $3^x -x \equiv 0 \pmod 7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Initially I though this would be a simple application of Fermat's little theorem, as $a^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod p$ can be more generally stated as $a^p \equiv a \pmod p$.

However, trying to apply that directly to the issue of $3^x \equiv x \pmod 7$ would require $x \equiv 3 \pmod 7$ and  $x \equiv 0 \pmod 7$, which is clearly not feasible.

Other ways of looking at the problem included  noting that $3^x - x$ would have to be some multiple of $7$, or that $7 | 3^x - x \Longleftrightarrow 3^x-x = 7d, d \in \mathbb{N}$, however I didn't find that representation any more useful. Is there a way of looking at this  that is more expressive, or is this the proper form and I just am not appling the correct tools to the task?

Comment: In this problem it is not hard to try all cases.

Comment: That's true, but what if 'p' (in this case 7) was large? Is trying all cases the only solution, or is there a more general form?

Comment: $a^{p-1}\equiv 0$?

Comment: Hint: look at numbers $x$ modulo $42=7(7-1)$.

Comment: Mod $7$, $3^x$ has periodicity $6$ and $x$ has periodicity $7$. So $3^x-x$ has periodicity at most $42$.

Comment: A brute force script seems to hint that $x$ is a solution whenever $x \equiv 2,4,5,27,31,36 \pmod 42$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at the congruence $3^x \mod 7$, you get
\begin{cases}
0\to 3^0 \equiv 1 \mod 7\\
1\to 3^1 \equiv 3 \mod 7\\
2\to 3^2 \equiv 2 \mod 7\\
3\to 3^3 \equiv 6 \mod 7\\
4\to 3^4 \equiv 4 \mod 7\\
5\to 3^5 \equiv 5 \mod 7\\
6\to 3^6 \equiv 1 \mod 7\\
\text{and so on...(because the cycle repeats)}
\end{cases}
So we can easily see that the cycle $3^x \mod7$ has periodicity $6$;, but $x \mod7$ has periodicity $7$, so the cycle $3^x -x \mod7$ has periodicity $42$. *Ergo* all the positive integers such that $3^x -x \equiv 0 \pmod 7$ are written in the form $$2+42n, 4+42n,5+42n,27+42n,31+42n \text{ or } 36+42n$$
Example: $3^{5+42n}-(5+42n) \equiv 3^{5+7\cdot 6n}-5 \equiv 5-5 \equiv 0 \pmod7$

Answer (score 1):

Since $3^2=2 [7]$, then $3^6=1\ [7]$, and $3^{6k+r}=3^r\ [7]$. Also, $7q+r=r\ [7]$. As a consequence, if $x=42k+r$ with $0\leqslant r<42$, we have $3^x-x=3^r-r [7]$. 
\
You only need to consider the cases where $0\leqslant x<42$. For example, when $x=2$ or $x=4$ or $x=5$, you have $3^x-x=0\ [7]$.

Answer (score 0):

I'll use the same idea than Taladris, but perhaps from other point of view.

The functions $f,g:\Bbb Z\rightarrow\Bbb Z_7$ are defined so:

$f$ maps $x$ to its class modulo $7$. This function is periodic and its period is $7$.

$g$ maps $x$ to the class of $3^x$. This function is periodic and its period (by LFT) divides $6$. You can easily check that the period is, in fact, $6$.

So $f-g$ is periodic and its period is $42$. Now, as Taladris said, search for solutions between $0$ and $42$.